# Can't push/pull to Github using Gitbox after password change

Tags: git, passwords, gitbox

I changed my Github password and now I'm unable to push/pull from any of my local repos to/from Github. Gitbox (http://www.gitboxapp.com/) prompts me for a username/password which I input (have double and triple checked!) but then fails with the error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/{myproject}/{myrepo}/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Doing a "defaults delete com.oleganza.gitbox" doesn't fix it either. :/

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

open Keychain Access.app, search for GitBox, and delete the relevant entry there (in the "All items" category in the left pane).

Then try GitBox again — it should accept the new password.